# Migrating existing Time to DateTime in Rails while keeping data intact

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, time, database-migration

Forgive me if I'm asking a silly question, but I've run into some trouble trying to update a `time` column to `datetime`.

Here's what the relevant part of my `schema.rb` looks like:

```
  create_table "shop_hours", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.time "from_hours"
    t.time "to_hours"
    t.string "day"
    t.integer "repair_shop_id"
    t.boolean "is_shop_open"
    t.integer "chain_id"
    t.integer "regions", default: [], array: true
    t.index ["repair_shop_id"], name: "index_shop_hours_on_repair_shop_id"
  end
```

Here's an example of random `ShopHour` object:

```
[67] pry(main)> ShopHour.find(439)
 #<ShopHour:0x00007ff05462d3a0
 id: 439,
 from_hours: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 15:00:00 UTC +00:00,
 to_hours: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 UTC +00:00,
 day: "Friday",
 repair_shop_id: 468,
 is_shop_open: true,
 chain_id: nil,
 regions: []>
```

Ultimately, I want to migrate the attributes `from_hours` and `to_hours` on all of my `ShopHour` tables so that they're of type `datetime`.

I'd also like to update the date on each `from_hours` and `to_hours` to be current.

I tried this migration, but ran into an error:

```
class ChangeShopHoursToDateTime < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    change_column :shop_hours, :from_hours, 'timestamp USING CAST(from_hours AS timestamp)'
    change_column :shop_hours, :to_hours, 'timestamp USING CAST(to_hours AS timestamp)'
  end
end
```

Here's the error I'm encountering:

```
== 20201021083719 ChangeShopHoursToDateTime: migrating ========================
-- change_column(:shop_hours, :from_hours, "timestamp USING CAST(from_hours AS timestamp)")
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR:  cannot cast type time without time zone to timestamp without time zone
LINE 1: ...s" ALTER COLUMN "from_hours" TYPE timestamp USING CAST(from_...
```

Please let me know if I can provide any more information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't automatically actually cast a time column to a timestamp as a time has no date component. Postgres actually correctly prevents you from doing this as the result would be ambiguous - which date should it really cast `12:45` to:

- 0 BC?
- the beginning of epoc time?
- todays date?

Ruby doesn't actually have a class to represent a time without a date component. The major difference is that Time is simple wrapper written in C that wraps a UNIX timestamp and DateTime is better at historical times. The fact that Rails just casts a `time` database column to a Time starting at 2000-01-01 is really just a strange yet pragmatic solution to the problem instead of creating something like a `TimeWithoutDate` class.

If you want to migrate a database column from time to timestamp / timestampz you need to tell the database which date you expect the time to be at:

```
class AddDatetimeColumnsToHours < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    add_column :shop_hours, :opens_at, :datetime
    add_column :shop_hours, :closes_at, :datetime
    ShopHour.update_all(
      [ "closes_at = (timestamp '2000-01-01') + to_hour, opens_at = (timestamp '2000-01-01') + from_hour" ]
    )
  end

  def down
    remove_column :shop_hours, :opens_at
    remove_column :shop_hours, :closes_at
  end
end
```

This adds two new columns and you should really consider just dropping the existing column and going with this naming scheme as methods that start with `to_` are by convention casting methods in Ruby (for example `to_s`, `to_a`, `to_h`) - `to_hour` is thus a really bad name.

Comment: Oh boy, what a fantastic answer. I want to thank you for taking the time to respond in such depth (also, in a non-condescending way). That explained everything I wanted to know. Thanks for making my morning!

edit: you're totally right about my usage of `to_`. That's...gross.